# MS Access VBA - Variable not defined error when variables have been declared

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a form with some fields that I want to transfer to a new form with the use of variables.  The settings for the form's code are 'Option Compare Database' and 'Option Explicit.'  I have declared four public variables just below this as follows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public LnNum As Long
Public InvLnNum As String
Public Inv As String
Public DefID As Long
```

Further down is the code to open the form.  I have a button set-up on the first form, and when it opens I want a few fields to copy over to the new form (these fields have the same names).  This is the code for that specific event:

```
Private Sub cmdNewDefect_Click()

LnNum = Me.LoanNumber.Value
InvLnNum = Me.InvestorLoanNumber.Value
Inv = Me.Investor.Value
DefID = Me.ID.Value

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmInvestorDefects"
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmInvestorDefects", acNewRec
Form_frmInvestorDefects.LoanNumber.Value = LnNum
Form_frmInvestorDefects.InvestorLoanNumber.Value = InvLnNum
Form_frmInvestorDefects.Investor.Value = Inv
Form_frmInvestorDefects.ID.Value = DefID

End Sub
```

When I click the button I get the error message, 'Compile Error: Variable Not Defined.'  I have another database with multiple forms that do the exact thing that I am wanting this form to do without issue.  The code is exactly the same, except that the event occurs on an After Update event instead of On Click, so I am stumped.  I have tried moving the variable declarations into the actual sub procedure with Dim statements instead of Public, but that doesn't work either.  I am thinking there is a setting or something that I am forgetting.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the form you are opening is:  "frmInvestorDefects"
Then try:

```
frmInvestorDefects.LoanNumber.Value = LnNum
```

Not sure why the 'Form_' prefix is required...
Not sure why the .Value part is needed either

```
frmInvestorDefects.LoanNumber = LnNum
```

or

```
[frmInvestorDefects].[LoanNumber] = LnNum
```